# Exclusive Queue with Semaphore

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, computer-science, semaphore

This is about a solution from the book “The Little Book of Semaphore” 2nd Ed. by Allen B. Downey. I feel the solution on “*Exclusive queue*” from the book (section 3.7.4) might not be correct. However, since this is very unlikely I request your feedback. **Below I provide ample context so that you may respond without referring to the book** which is available online under GNU copyright though.

*Btw, this is by no means related to any course assignment*

**Problem Statement:**

For ballroom dance, there are many dancers categorized into leaders and followers, arriving randomly. We need to enforce that at most one pair gets to dance and that the pair must include a leader and a follower. 
For example, if many leaders arrive, they got to wait for followers to pair up. At this point, if many followers arrive, still all of them cannot proceed in pairs, rather only one pair gets to dance while rest awaits.
We are allowed to use semaphores (in addition to shared and local variables as needed) to apply the synchronization constraints.

A semaphore is defined to be an entity that has a value which either can be incremented (by unity) atomically by ‘*signal*’ or can be decremented (by unity) atomically by ‘*wait*’ commands but cannot be read for its current value. Furthermore, a ‘*wait*’, after decrementing, if results in a negative value then the calling thread will be blocked. On the other hand, every ‘*signal*’, besides incrementing, will always wake up (unblock) one of the waiting (blocked) threads if any. A semaphore can be initialized with any integer value – zero or positive or negative.

With this, the solution from the book is as follows (listing 3.18 and 3.19 from the book).

**Solution from the book:**

*’mutex’ and queues are all semaphores. ‘mutext’ is initialized with ‘1’ while both queues are initialized with ‘0’. Shared variables ‘leaders’ and ‘followers’ are both initialized with ‘0’*

```
       Leader                             Follower
       ======                             ========

1      mutex.wait()                       mutex.wait()
2      if followers > 0                   if leaders > 0
3            followers--                        leaders--
4            followerQueue.signal()             leaderQueue.signal()
5      else                               else
6            leaders++                          followers++
7            mutex.signal()                     mutex.signal()
8            leaderQueue.wait()                 followerQueue.wait()
9      end-if                             end-if
10     dance()                            dance()
11     mutex.signal()
```

**My Concern:**

Based on above solution, in order to enforce any new pair not to proceed until current pair finishes, only one of the current pair will issue a '*signal*' (line #11 for leader) after their dance (line #10). 
However, I could imagine a situation which might disobey the constraints that only a pair dances and the pair must consist of one from each category – leader and follower.
Imagine, few leaders arrived first and all of them would be waiting at *leaderQueue* (line #8). At this point, a single follower, say F1, arrives. F1 will get the *mutex* and will awaken a leader, say L1, and both of them will proceed to dance. F1 is still holding the *mutex* (with its current value set to ‘0’). Interestingly with a bit of exaggeration, the leader (say L1) gets to dance and finishes; and even goes on to signal that the pair's done while the follower F1 is still preparing to dance.  The *mutex* is now ‘1’ and imagine another follower, say F2, arrives. F2 will get the *mutex* now and will awaken another leader, say L2. Both F2 and L2 proceed to dance while F1 has not finished dancing yet. Thus we’ve a situation that breaches the desired constraint that only a single pair dancing at a time.

Please let me know, if I’m missing something.

*P.S. I sincerely thank Prof. Downey for this amazing book*

Comment: I also thought about the situation you are describing while reading the solution. I would say that you are correct but I didn't spend much time on this problem. It may be instructional to test your hypothesis with a program (making the leaders' dances last a lot less than followers') and eventually mailing the author with your thoughts.

Comment: @ Margaret Bloom  - Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the leaders and followers are defined as follows:

Leaders:

```
mutex.wait()
if followers > 0:
    followers--
    followerQueue.signal()
else:
    leaders++
    mutex.signal()
    leaderQueue.wait()

dance()
rendezvous.wait()
mutex.signal()
```

Followers:

```
mutex.wait()
if leaders > 0:
    leaders--
    leaderQueue.signal()
else:
    followers++
    mutex.signal()
    followerQueue.wait()

dance()
rendezvous.signal()
```

The rendezvous parts now handles your concern. However, I think a solution with two mutexes and one rendezvous point would be a nicer alternative (unless one can disprove it)

Here is the code for that:

Leaders:

```
mutex1.lock();
rendezvous.wait();
dance();
mutex1.unlock();
```

Followers:

```
mutex2.lock();
rendezvous.wait();
dance();
mutex2.unlock();
```

For completeness rendezvous.wait() is a higher order statement. In reality for follower we would have

```
followerArrived.signal()
leaderArrived.wait()
```

And for leader we would have

```
leaderArrived.signal()
followerArrived.wait()
```

Where leaderArrived and followerArrived are semahpores initialized to 1.